# Sunburst partition data overwritten by second sunburst on same page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

*Posting both question & answer here to save somebody else the same trouble later...*

When I create two sunburst charts using [d3.layout.partition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout), the first sunburst's slice proportions are overwritten by the second sunburst's slice proportions upon resize of the slices.

The two charts pass different `.value` accessor functions into the partition layout, e.g.

```
d3.layout.partition()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return 1; });
```

vs.

```
d3.layout.partition()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

And they generate their own list of nodes that are not shared between the two sunbursts. However, if I re-call the `d3.svg.arc` generator to resize to larger radius (but not change overall proportions), the slice angles are suddenly overwritten.

See the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/ab8cf15534f7fec5ac6d

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that while `partition.nodes()` **seems** to generate a new data structure (e.g if you give it some `.key` functions, it writes the extra properties (e.g. `.x`, `.y`, `.dx`, `dy`) to the underlying data and **does not make a copy** of the data. Thus if the data structure is shared between the two charts, these `.x`, `.y`, `.dx`, `dy` properties will bleed through to the other graphs.

This seems like a bug to me, but in reading [this old GitHub issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1145) it seems to be treated as "by design". Perhaps it will be reconsidered in future versions.

One workaround is to use something like Lodash/Underscore `cloneDeep` or Angular's `copy` to make each chart have it's own copy of the data.

```
makeSunburst(null, _.cloneDeep(root), countAccessorFn);
makeSunburst(null, _.cloneDeep(root), sizeAccessorFn);
```

See example here: http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/e9efb830439247eea1be

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to copying the whole dataset for each chart would be to simply recompute the partition before re-rendering.

Instead of having `makeSunburst()` be a function of the accessor, make it a function of the partition. Pass a different partition function to each chart:

```
// create separate partition variables
var countPartition = d3.layout.partition().sort(null).value(countAccessorFn);
var sizePartition = d3.layout.partition().sort(null).value(sizeAccessorFn);

// make the charts as a function of partition
charts.push(makeSunburst(root, countPartition));
charts.push(makeSunburst(root, sizePartition));
```

Then before applying the transition, simply update the `nodes` variable to reflect the associated partition:

```
addToRadius: function(radiusChange) {
  radius += radiusChange;
  ringRadiusScale.range([0, radius]);

  // update the data before re-rendering each chart
  nodes = partition.nodes(dataRoot);
  path.transition().attr('d', arc);
}
```

Now when you update each chart, it is using the correct partition.

Here's an [**updated example**](http://bl.ocks.org/jshanley/86e3bc1b231e9772b16d).

Comment: Yes, that's another valid workaround. Neither workaround should be necessary, IMO, but I guess the D3 authors didn't like the wrapping of original data.

Comment: Try to imagine what would happen if your data was constantly being updated. Copying the whole dataset for each chart makes sense if you know the data is never going to change, but that doesn't seem like it should be the default behavior. There would need to be a way to keep those copies of the data in sync with one another. What if you were making 20 charts? Should d3 make 20 copies of the data and try to synchronize changes across all 20 of them? It makes more sense to me to just recompute the partition, since that is all that differs between the charts.

Comment: But it's inconsistent with how other parts of D3 work, e.g. Pie layout wraps the original data in a `.data` property.